# Autowiring configuration class spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm wondering whether it's possible to autowire a class annotated with @Configuration into any annotated class (@Component, @SpringBootTest, etc)? I know it's possible between @Configuration classes, but I can't find a straight answer on if it's possible outside @Configuration classes (both test and non-test classes). Sample code to illustrate what I mean below:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    //Anything in here
}

//any non-Configuration annotation
public class Autowired {
    @Autowire
    Config config; //like this
}
```

Comment: Yes you can as they are just specialized `@Component`s just like `@Service` and `@Repository` etc. Should you, probably not but it depends.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking at the source code of [@Configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.java#L424) annotation you can see it's annotated itself with `@Component`, making annotated classes with it also Spring components, so making them available for injection.

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Configuration {
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can autowire configuration class as @configuration annotation contains @component

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).